# How to remove characters from string in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios6

I have a string "1.2345677".
I want only "1.23" for further use.
  how to remove other string. 
Any Help
Thanks.

Comment: If you mean a string, [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612337/objective-c-nsstring-and-substring). If you mean a float, [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063721/ios-objective-c-how-to-get-2-decimal-rounded-float-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
NSString *origString = @"1.2345677";
NSString *subString = [origString substringToIndex:3];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *mainstr = @"1.2345677";
float conver = [mainstr floatValue];
NSString *floatedstr =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",conver];
```

You can also do it with

```
NSNumberFormatter *format = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[format setFormat:@"0.##"];
NSLog(@"%@", [format stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:25.342]]);
```